# Serving .js and .css files that are outside of public folder in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, css, file, directory

I've got this structure in my projects:

[]public

- index.php
- style.css
- script.js

[]controller

[]model

[]view

- base.html.php
- []view1
- - view1.html.php
- - view1.css
- - view1.js

.htaccess

In public folder, which is the root's server, there's .js and .css files which must be accessed by the browser.
However, I've more and more oftenly css and javascript files particular to one view. As css interact with html and js with css (via selectors), It is easiest for me to have all theses files in one folder (like the view1 folder in the example above).

Is there a way to do this ?
I guess my best bet would be to act in the main controller. When it serves a view depending of the url, it should move the js and css files (or duplicate them) from the view folder to the public folder.
But can it be moved temporary instead of permanent ?
And does it costs lots of server resources ?

thaks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static files (css, js, html) should be served together with your public directory. Why? Because they're what you want to serve to the client, like you said.

To serve a client a file, the server must allow the client to request the file, putting it outside of the client's access points defeats the point.

But regardless, to give you an answer to your actual question, yes, you can do this by adding a rewrite rule for an non-existant path, such as `view1` in public to use the `view1` path in your `view` folder:

```
RewriteRule ^view1/(.*)$ ../view/view1/$1 [L,NC]
```

This will rewrite any request `view1/*` to `view/view1/*` rather than `public/view1/*`.

Comment: I come back late, sorry. I don't want access possible bottom public folder, as view contains php (the purpose of public folder is to protect what's behind) but at same time I want to group html/css/js in same folder for convenience, so I have created a method that copy css/js in public folder to serve them to client like this : <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= copyToPublic('file') ?>"/> Thanks!